# Keyboard shortcut between two playground files of xcode

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, swift-playground

I have couple playground files to work at same time. Is there any shortcut to switch in these playground files of Xcode?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways to realise this. The first way is to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> to swap between instances of Xcode.

You can also open a new tab inside your playground by using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

You can then swap between the tabs using:

Next tab: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>

Previous tab: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>

Comment: Great. Very convenient.